# Emulating the registry and running an executable to use that registry

Tags: c#, c++, registry, process

I am currently writing a program that takes other programs, copies them, and stores them in a different folder. The point of my program is to be able to run other programs with different settings. For programs that use config files, this works perfectly. However, for some of the programs, the config values they hold are kept in the registry.

I was wondering two different things:

1) Is it possible to create a "fake" registry

2) Would I be able to run an executable inside a sandbox to use the fake registry?

Thanks!

Comment: This will be extremely difficult, and will involve native code.

Comment: That is all fine, I'm trying to learn as much as I can. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: So basically you want to virtualize an application, but only registry access? Interesting

Comment: @Charles just hook loads of APIs. How hard could it be?

Comment: @David I wouldn't know, I've never done it before, hence the question on SO.

Comment: @Charles It's just going to be 20 or 30 hooks and a re-implementation of the Windows registry APIs. Doesn't sound like more than a couple of years worth of work, including testing.

Comment: @David This is my personal project, so I don't mind. If you have an answer on where to find the resources to get started or even some hints, please do so.

Comment: @charles learn all the registry apis and you will need all of them. Get to grips with detours or another hooking library. Accept that new versions of windows or even service packs will break your app.

Comment: Have you thought about using a virtual machine instead? David's comments are right-on, but I don't think you're accepting the immense magnitude of difficulty this will involve. I don't know about you, but I get bored with personal projects that drag on for longer than 2 years! By that time, a new version of Windows will come out and stuff will break. You'll spend more time chasing your tail than you will implementing functionality in the first place. This is what VMs are explicitly designed for, and this reinvention of the wheel will end up more like a trapezoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using VirtualRegistry to Redirect Registry Keys on Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/09/27/using-virtualregistry-to-redirect-registry-keys-on-windows-vista.aspx)

[Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have not used this before, but it sure looks promising.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vista has some [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Registry_virtualization) support.

One thing that you could do for keys under [HKCU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#HKEY_CURRENT_USER_.28HKCU.29) is create a new user profile and run the app with matching credentials in order to force usage of a specific [HKCU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#HKEY_CURRENT_USER_.28HKCU.29).

If you are feeling brave have a look at the registry [file format](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?search=registry&button=GO!).

**Edit:**

[Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) looks interesting. Registry specific [features](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?SandboxHierarchy#keys)

Comment: @David Heffernan: If programs store settings inside the HKCU it would be possible to "runas" those with different user profiles and associated settings.

Comment: Links from the wotsit.org page are broken